# Node.js app on openshift

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, openshift

I have issues with an express application that works fine locally

```
node server.js
```

but has this error on openshift:

```
...

    Uninitialized option at server.js:104:9 events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
...
```

I have understood that this would be an issue with my .createServer().listen implementation.
My code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
....//I cut code from here..Bunch of middleware..
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');

....//My routes were here...
var app = express();

//HTTP
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
http.createServer(app).listen(server_port);

var ssl = {
key: fs.readFileSync('keys/key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('keys/cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(ssl, app).listen(443);
```

I'd also like to have working ssl, but i couldn't find info on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
server = require('http').createServer(app)

port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080  
ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";

server.listen(port, ip);
```

Has always worked for me in the past. I'm not entirely confident that rearranging the stuff you have to match (since yours is almost identical) but its how I have it working in my current nodejs app. Also, for further context can you paste in the lines from Uninitialized option at server.js:104:9 events.js:72, if you've done so already can you mark them? from what I can see your stuff *should* work.

Comment: For some reason this fixes it, Thanks. Can you have https/ssl on open shift?

Comment: I now just realized why you were getting that error, its because you were starting both a http server and an https server. On Openshift there is no need to do that as your application already listens on 80, 443, 8080, 8443